# OpenSource .NET FTP Application

Tags: ftp, ftp-client, net-ftp

can somebody please provide me link to some FTP Client application with complete functionality like Filezilla or others like that.. 
i am looking for some OpenSource Solution and should be developed in .Net (C#, VB.Net).

i went through many FTP libraries. like NetFtp and many other. but i dont have enough time to develop one from scratch. i need some pre developed and than will modify it according to my requirements.
i want to implement restriction on file upload and no. of files uploaded. (on the base of logged in user).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many FTP Servers that have the capability built in to restrict certain files types, set quotas, throttle bandwidth, and limit the files uploaded.

You may want to consider getting a server that already supports this functionality and then you can use any standard FTP client that you want.